# Regex: How to replace all characters except a word/sequence of pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following strings:

```
"ft-2 MY AWESOME ft-12 APP"
"MY AWESOME APP"
"MY AWESOME APP ft-20"
```

I want to do some modification ([titleization](https://github.com/granth/titleize) in this case) on the words except `ft-<NUMBER>` parts. `ft-<NUMBER>` word can appear anywhere. It can appear multiple times or may not be present at all. After string manipulation, the end results should look like this:

```
"ft-2 My Awesome ft-12 App"
"My Awesome App"
"My Awesome App ft-20"
```

Is it possible to write any regex in Ruby that can do this transformation?

I tried like this:

```
"ft-4 MY AWESOME ft-5 APP".gsub(/(?<=ft-\d\s).*/) { |s| s.titleize }
```

I got this: `ft-4 My Awesome Ft 5 App` in return.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried with `gsub` but I couldn't figure out to match all the characters except the pattern.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: `gsub(/(?<=ft-\d\s).*/)` was my naive attempt.

Comment: Yes, but `gsub` requires a replacement part.

Comment: I tried like this: `"ft-4 MY AWESOME ft-5 APP".gsub(/(?<=ft-\d\s).*/) { |s| s.titleize }`. I got this: `ft-4 My Awesome Ft 5 App` in return.

Comment: `"ft-2 MY AWESOME ft-12 APP".gsub(/(?<=\A|\s)\p{L}+(?=\z|\s)/) { |m| m.downcase.capitalize }`

Comment: @Musaffa there is no `String#titleize` method in ruby.

Comment: I've mentioned in the question the gem I'm using (just to contextualize).

@mudasobwa Your regex works great! Can you please post this as an answer with some explanations? Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather stick with a word boundary than a custom whitespace boundary.

Comment: how about something like `str.gsub(/\B[A-Z]+/){$&.downcase}` (see [non ruby demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oWq6Td/1))

Comment: @Wiktor, with regard to your comment about [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) requiring a replacement part, recall that one form of the method is `gsub(pattern) → enumerator`, so we could write, for example, `"123456".gsub(/../).reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i } #=> 102`. I recall using that form of the method, but don't remember the specifics.

Comment: I just meant that there must be something that acts like a replacement. Whatever that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(?<=ft-\d\s).*` pattern matches any location that is preceded with `ft-<digits><whitespace>`, and then matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars that you `titleize`.

You need to match whole words that do not start with `ft-<NUMBER>` pattern. Then all you need is to downcase the match and capitalize it:

```
s.gsub(/\b(?!ft-\d)\p{L}+/) { | m | m.capitalize }
```

Or, if you prefer to use `$1` variable, add a capturing group:

```
s.gsub(/\b(?!ft-\d)(\p{L}+)/) { $1.capitalize }
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/1pt1DM)

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - first of all, assert the position before a letter (because the next consuming pattern is `\p{L}` that matches a letter)
- `(?!ft-\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next 2 letters are `ft` that are followed with a `-` and a digit
- `(\p{L}+)` - a capturing group matching 1+ letters (that is later referred to with `$1` in the replacement block)

The [`capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) *"returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase"*.

Comment: Is it possible to get the rest as a sentence instead of individual words with `\b`? `titleize` gem handles small words like and, of, in etc if they are in the middle of a sentence.

For "ft-5 MY AWESOME APP OF RAILS ft-20", I want to get "ft-5 My Awesome App of Rails ft-20". Here `of` is handled by titleize gem if it is in the middle of a collection of words.

Comment: You will need to handle them in the negative lookahead, I am afraid. Like `\b(?!ft-\d|(?:off?|in(?:to)?|at)\b)`

Answer (score 4):

```
R = /
    [[:alpha:]]+ # match one or more uppercase or lowercase letters
    (?=\s|\z)    # match a whitespace or end of string (positive lookahead)
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

def doit(str)
  str.gsub(R) { |s| s.capitalize }
end

doit "ft-2 MY AWESOME ft-12 APP"
  #=> "ft-2 My Awesome ft-12 App" 
doit "MY AWESOME APP"
  #=> "My Awesome App" 
doit "MY AWESOME APP ft-20"
  #=> "My Awesome App ft-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what you want but I think that what you want to to downcase and then titleize a string

I have something similar on one of my projects

```
#lib/core_ext/string.rb
class String
  def my_titleize
    humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
  end
end
```

> humanize(options = {}) public Capitalizes the first word, turns
>   underscores into spaces, and strips a trailing ‘_id’ if present. Like
>   titleize, this is meant for creating pretty output.
>
> The capitalization of the first word can be turned off by setting the
>   optional parameter capitalize to false. By default, this parameter is
>   true.